# Why there is an error when connecting Three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, tree

An error of the following type, and it does not appear in all browsers: An uncaught error of the type: The module specifier "three" could not be resolved. Relative links must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Connecting modules

```
  <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.138.0/build/three.module.js",
                "OrbitControls": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.138.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js",
                "GLTFLoader": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.138.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="./assets/js/main.js" type="module"></script>
```

Start file main.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {GLTFLoader} from "GLTFLoader";
import {OrbitControls} from "OrbitControls";
```

Comment: if you swap import order does it still throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try first locally , after swap with CDN .
Also import your controls/ loader/ directly from your main.js will avoid some issues

index.html

```
<script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "../build/three.module.js" <!-- retarget it -->
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script type="module" src="./main.js">
```

main.js

```
import * as THREE from "three";

import { OrbitControls } from "../file/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";// also retarget them

import { GLTFLoader } from "../file/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import { RGBELoader } from "../file/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader.js";
```